# Auto generate Docs and replace Doc text with text from Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I want a script that can generate new documents based on a range of cells in a sheet (say A2:A20), and replace the text with the adjacent cell values in the sheet. So column A for `{Name}` and column B for `{Company Name}`.

```
function docReplace() 
{ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var names = s.getRange('A2:A30');

  var companyNames = s.getRange('B2:B30');

  for (var i; i < names.getValues().length; i++)
  {

    var name = names.getValues[i];
    var companyName = companyNames.getValues[i];

    doc = DocumentApp.create(companyName + ' Outreach Draft');
    var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    var text = body.setText("Dear {Name} I am interested in connecting with {Company Name} to inquire about potential partnership. Thank you"); // this would already be written in the doc.

    body.replaceText("{Name}", name); 

    body.replaceText("{Company Name}", companyName); 
  }
}
```

Hope I'm on the right track. It seems like this requires me to have the specific spreadsheet open.

Comment: Which do you want to use `doc = DocumentApp.create(companyName + ' Outreach Draft')` or `var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody()`? And, I cannot understand about `this would already be written in the doc.` in your sample script. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation and your goal?

Comment: Two things - 1) the code you have does run from the spreadsheet it is bound to, but it doesn't necessarily have to be open to work, it all depends on what you are using to trigger the function.  For the document - Another approach would be to create a template doc with all of the formatting that you want and the merge fields already in the body copy, then in your loop make a copy, rename it, and skip right to the find and replace.

Comment: @KrispinMiller Thank you. I'll give this a try. Can one do this with Gmail instead of Docs?

Comment: Yes.  Check out this for some background  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails